# Retrieving all values from IGrouping

Tags: c#, linq, list, fileinfo, igrouping

I currently have:

```
UIEnumerable <IGrouping<PortableKey, FileInfo>>
```

From this code :

```
var queryDupFiles = from file in fileList
    group file by new PortableKey { Name = file.Name, Length = file.Length } 
    into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g;
```

where the code for PortableKey is:

```
    public class PortableKey
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long Length { get; set; }
    }
```

Basically filtering and grabbing all files that are duplicate. How do I get it so that I have all of the FileInfo in this manner?

```
List<FileInfo> list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an additional `from` clause:

```
from f in g
select f
```

This translate into `.GroupBy(...).SelectMany(g => g)`